# dplyr count observations per day

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregation

I have the following data

```
Name         Date                                   Message
Ted Foe      2011-06-10T05:06:30+0000               I love this product
Sina Fall    2011-06-10T05:07:33+0000               Not my type of product
Steve Hoe    2011-06-11T05:06:30+0000               Great Discussion! Thanks
Selda Dee    2011-06-13T05:12:30+0000               Seen elsewhere
Steven Hoe   2011-06-13T03:17:31+0000               Where?
Selda Dee    2011-06-13T05:17:56+0000               Tinder
```

I want to aggregate by days so that I end up with a time series like this

```
Date            Number of Posts
2011-06-10      2
2011-06-11      1
2011-06-12      0
2011-06-13      3
```

I already tried the following

```
summary_df <- df %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(comments = count(message))
```

But this is not working. Any quick dplyr based solution would be great.

Thanks for the help!

Cheers, Raoul

Comment: You need to use `tally` or you can use `count`, but then you don't have to group because `count` already does this for you. Have a look at the examples in `?tally`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grouped by the 'Date' column after converting to `Date` class, we get the number of rows (`n()`) with `summarise`.  If we need the 'Date' elements that are missing in the original dataset, create a new dataset with the sequence of minimum to maximum 'Date' and do a `left_join`

```
df1 <- df %>%
          group_by(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
          summarise(comments = n())
expand.grid(Date = seq(min(df1$Date), max(df1$Date), by = '1 day')) %>%
         left_join(., df1)
```

Comment: Thanks, however I get the following two error messages:

`Error: unexpected '=' in:
"    group_by(created_time = as.Date(created_time)) %>%
    summarise(message() =" `

and 

`Error in seq.default(min(posts1$created_time), max(posts1$created_time),  : 
  'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite`

Comment: @rkuebler  I was not getting any error based on the example you showed.  Also, I find you are using wrong command.  If you check my post, i have not used  `message()`

Comment: I am sorry, I changed too many things. Now it is wonderfully working. Unfortunately the script does put NA for the days without comments. Any chance to get zeros instead? I can also only see the NAs in the console but not in the resulting frame. When I export as CSV they are also not there... Any help with this is really appreciated! Many thanks beforehand!

Comment: @rkuebler  Are you using `Rstudio`?  If it is not in the resulting dataset, no need to worry.

Comment: Yes I am using RStudio. Unfortunately no zeros in the exported dataset. However, I would like to have them in there too. Any idea how to solve that? Thank you so much!

Comment: @rkuebler By default the `left_join` gives NA for the missing values.  If you want zeros', then use `replace`, i.e. `%>% left_join(., df1) %>% mutate(comments = replace(comments, is.na(comments), 0))`

Comment: Date             Comment
2009-11-02   1
2010-10-13   3
2010-10-14   1
2010-10-21   5

I see in the console the 0s, but I don't see them in the data frame displayed in rstudio. When I export with write.csv2(df1, file ="dailycomments.csv",row.names=FALSE) I don't get them either but the output above.

Comment: @rkuebler  You have to assign it to a new object before exporting it. `df2 <- expand.grid(Date = seq(min(df1$Date), max(df1$Date), by = '1 day')) %>%
         left_join(., df1) %>% mutate(comments = replace(comments, is.na(comments), 0)); wirte.csv(df2, file="dailycomments.csv",row.names=FALSE)`

Comment: Thx, I just see my big error. Totally blind I was ;) You are great help! Thank you so much!

Comment: I tried to upvote, but I am still not allowed due to my low reputation score. Be sure I will come back, once I have my required 15 points!